# Websocket-Node Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Does this [library](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node) support callbacks on `.send` from the server? The very example case that is provided on the README, does not support. If I just update the `connection.send` for the client to

```
connection.send('somedata', function (data) {
    console.log("this is a callback");
});
```

And update the `connection.('message'...` for the server to:

```
connection.on('message', function(message, cb) {
    console.log(cb);
});
```

I always get undefined from the server. How can I pass callbacks?

Comment: Can you see a message from callback fn...??. I am using socket.io so it is differ from your libs..!

Comment: @hoanganh17b, yes I know for a fact `socket.io` supports the cb because I've used it before. With this library, I do see `console.log(b)`, but not because I've called it from the other end of the websocket. I think the callback here is used for error handling -- i.e. if there were any errors in sending request, the variable `b` here would contain the error. Right now it is just null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the lib did not supports callback function, you can easily implement by yourself follow this pattern

```
connection.send('somedata', function (data) {
   informCommingData(data, myListener)
});

function informCommingData(data,fn){
    fn(data)
}


function myListener(data){
    // Dosomethinghere
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is working? What's the pattern on the receiver side? How is `data` passed from the server to this client?

Answer (score 0):

I think the project WebSockets-Callback would be the easiest solution

```
wscb.send({cmd: 'Hello server!'},
    function(response){
        //do something...
    }
)
```